# Get a property of task? in Gradle kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to convert my `build.gradle` file to `build.gradle.kts`.
I almost do that but only one problem left.
I don't have any idea how to convert code below.

Kotlin

```
import org.asciidoctor.gradle.AsciidoctorTask

...

apply(plugin = "org.asciidoctor.convert")

val snippetsDir = file("build/generated-snippets")

tasks.named<AsciidoctorTask>("asciidoctor") {
    attributes(
        mapOf(
            "snippets" to snippetsDir
        )
    )
    inputs.dir(snippetsDir)
    dependsOn("test")
}

tasks.withType<BootJar> {
    dependsOn("asciidoctor")

    // This is the problem!
    //  from("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
    //      into("static/docs")
    //  }
}
```

Please help me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Tasks documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:locating_tasks) : you can access `asciidoctor` tasks using *Kotlin delegated properties*, and then access its properties like `outputDir`

```
tasks.withType<org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar> {
    dependsOn("asciidoctor")

    // This was the problem!
    val asciidoctor by tasks.getting(AsciidoctorTask::class)
    from("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
          into("static/docs")
    }
}
```